# Minimum of two norms in $\mathbb R^2$ needs not be a norm

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I know that if $\|x\|$ and $\|x\|'$ are norms, then $\min (\|x\|,\|x\|')$  needs not be a norm.

Is there any counterexample in $\mathbb R^2$ which shows that $\min (\|x\|,\|x\|')$ really is not a norm? This should probably be easy but I can't find one.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\|(x,y)\|_1=|x|+2|y|$ and $\|(x,y)\|_2=2|x|+|y|.$

Let $f(p)=\min(\|p\|_1,\|p\|_2).$

Let $p_1=(2,1)$ and $p_2=(1,2).$

Then $f(p_1)+f(p_2)=4+4=8<9=f(p_1+p_2).$

Answer (score 4):

The canonical norms on $\mathbb R^2$ are 
$$
\|(x,y)\|_\infty=\max\{|x|,|y|\},\ \ \|(x,y)\|_1=|x|+|y|,\ \ \|(x,y)\|_2=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}.
$$
An example cannot come directly from these, because we have $\|\cdot\|_\infty\leq\|\cdot\|_2\leq\|\cdot\|_1$. But let us construct a new norm,
$$
\|(x,y)\|_c=\frac{2\|(x,y)\|_\infty+\|(x,y)\|_1}3.
$$

Now, if $$\alpha(x,y)=\min\{\|(x,y)\|_c,\|(x,y)\|_2\},$$ we have 
$$
\left(2,3/2\right)=\left(1,1/2\right)+(1,1).
$$
We also have 
$$
\alpha(2,3/2)=\min\left\{\frac{4+2+3/2}3,\sqrt{4+\frac94}\right\}=\min\left\{\frac52,\frac52\right\}=\frac52,
$$
$$
\alpha(1,1/2)=\min\left\{\frac{2+3/2}3 ,\frac{\sqrt5}2\right\}=\frac{\sqrt5}2,
$$
$$
\alpha(1,1)=\min\left\{\frac{2+1+1}3,\sqrt2 \right\}=\frac43.
$$
As $\sqrt5/2+4/3<2.46<5/2$, 
$$
\alpha((1,1/2)+(1,1))> \alpha(1,1/2)+\alpha(1,1),
$$
contradicting the triangle inequality. So $\alpha$ is not a norm.

Answer (score 1):

To visualize the top answer, the unit sphere in the norms $|x|+2|y|$ and $2|x|+|y|$ are convex sets

[image]

The unit sphere in $\max(|x|+2|y|,2|x|+|y|)$ and $\min(|x|+2|y|,2|x|+|y|)$ are the intersection and union of two sets. The intersection of two convex sets is convex, so $\max$ of two norms is a norm. The union of two convex sets is not always convex, so $\min$ of two norms is not always a norm.

[image]$\hskip2cm$[image]