# If $\|\cdot\|_{\alpha}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\beta}\|$ are norms, show that $\max\{\|\cdot\|_\alpha, \|\cdot\|_\beta\}$ is a norm. What about the min?

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces

If $\|\cdot\|_{\alpha}$  and $\|\cdot\|_{\beta}$ are norms, show that $\max\{\|\cdot\|_\alpha, \|\cdot\|_\beta\}$ is a norm.  What about the min?

How to solve this problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you tell us what you tried to solve this problem? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: For example, do you know definition of a norm? There are couple of axioms. Have you tried to prove that any of them hold?

Comment: Well a couple of $3$ actually...

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369816/maximum-of-two-norms-is-norm and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2262310/minimum-of-two-norms-in-mathbb-r2-needs-not-be-a-norm

Comment: @zwim couple can mean both two and arbitrary small number.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your reply I really appreciate it